# Always vs forever in Verilog HDL

Tags: verilog, hdl, icarus

What are the difference between the `always` keyword (***not*** the `always @` block) and `forever` keyword in Verilog HDL?

```
always #1 a=!a;
forever #1 a=!a;
```

Here are my findings but I can't still quite draw the line between the two:

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog):

> The **always** keyword acts similar to the "C" construct while(1) {..} in the sense that it will execute forever.

From [electroSofts](http://www.electrosofts.com/verilog/loop_statements.html):

> The **forever** instruction continuously repeats the statement that follows it. Therefore, it should be used with procedural timing controls (otherwise it hangs the simulation).

Could someone give a clearer explanation on this? Thank you!

Comment: Similar question , you may find the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938158/use-of-forever-and-always-statements

Comment: Apparently I haven't seen that question in my searches here and even in Google, I wonder why. Anyway, thank you @chitranna!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `always` construct can be used at the module level to create a procedural block that is always triggered.  Typically it is followed by an event control, e.g., you might write, within a module, something like:

- `always @(posedge clk) <do stuff>`
- `always @(en or d) <do stuff>`
- `always @* <do stuff>`, can also use `@(*)`

This is the typical way to write latches, flops, etc.

The `forever` construct, in contrast, is a procedural statement that should typically only be used in test-bench code.  It can occur within `always` and `initial` blocks and other statements, but cannot occur directly within a module.  For instance, you can use it to write things like:

```
initial begin
  if (do_random_testing)
  begin
    forever #100 input = $random(...);
  end
  else if (read_from_file)
  begin
     ... read inputs from a file or whatever ...
  end
end
```

It wouldn't be legal to write something like `forever #1 a=!a;` as a top-level construct in a module.  It has to be put, e.g., in an `always` block, an `initial` block, a `task`, or similar.